# Why can't I create a Q#create project on VisualStudio Code with QDK || ISSUE :command "'quantum.newProject' failed.)"

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, quantum-computing, q#, new-project

help regarding the issue below would be really appreciated :

`Command 'Q#: Create new project...' resulted in an error (Running the contributed command: 'quantum.newProject' failed.)`

I was trying to follow this exercice : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/learn/modules/qsharp-create-first-quantum-development-kit/2-install-quantum-development-kit-code

after downloading and running the latest versions of .NET CORE, VSCODE, I can run "Q# Install command line project templates" but can't run "Q# Create a new project :  [See screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPK5Q.png) [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYAYg.png) [CODE SOURCE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7isA.png)
I already done this exercice in May last year but for some reasons I get stuck at the very beginning of the process now.

Could it be a version issue ? I remember that the tutorial was different (May 2020) than the one above I shared to you. Unfortunately I can't find the previous tutorial as it has been updated since.

I tried to uninstall the latest versions to reinstall the versions I downloaded in May : useless, I get the same issue.

Many thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with an older version v0.14.2011120240

It seems the new version isn't stable yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Quantum J. I manually uploaded this version and it has worked althought I muss run it everytime I want to create a new project... but at least it works. 
Do you have to do so aswell ?

Comment: Therefore I have been able to create the helloquantumworld, I get stuck for the second one but there is no proper issue, it's just that the code doesn't run what it should. I assume I have to open a new request regarding that. 
when I run QuantumRNG with dotnet run, I still get helloquantum world instead of ZERO or ONE....

Comment: Make sure you are in the right project folder and that you have saved your .qs file.
Otherwise the dotnet run will not know what to compile and in your case will still compile the helloquantumworld

Comment: Wahou... thanks again QuantumJ. I feel really stupid... I thought it would be saved automatically after any change in the code. I'll becareful now, thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Install NodeJS: https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4-x64.msi

Then restart VS Code.

"The below steps currently has a dependency to install node.js including npm. We are working on removing that dependency. Alternatively, use our the command line templates to create a Q# project , or use Visual Studio."

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/quantum/install-command-line-qdk?tabs=tabid-vscode